# Как создать самозаверяющийся сертификат с помощью PowerShell для создания SSLstream

Tags: c#, ssl, powershell, x509certificate

Поставил перед собой цель, сделать небольшое клиент-серверное приложение с использованием шифрования. Нашёл [документацию по SSLstream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

Возник вопрос с созданием сертификата, довольно долго лазил по интернету, и в конечном итоге нашёл один рабочий вариант через использование утилиты makecert:

```
makecert -sv RootCA.pvk -r -n "CN=имясервера" RootCA.cer

makecert -ic RootCA.cer -iv RootCA.pvk -n "CN=имясервера" -sv  TempCert.pvk -pe -sky exchange TempCert.cer

cert2spc TempCert.cer TempCert.spc
```

Затем, экспортировал закрытый ключ в контейнер PFX:

```
pvkimprt -pfx TempCert.spc TempCert.pvk
```

После чего PFX файл импортировал в персональное хранилище сертификатов на сервере.   RootCA.cer импортирую в хранилище доверенных корневых центров сертификации на клиенте и на сервере. Запускаю пример из документации SslTcpServer.exe с параметром TempCert.cer, а клиент SslTcpClient.exe  <имясервера>

Вопрос следующий:

Утилита makecert, как я понял, устарела. С помощью каких команд PowerShell (версия старше 5.0, на win 10) можно добиться тех же результатов?

По темам связанным с сертификатами прошу отвечать максимально подробно, т.к. в этой теме всё ещё слабоват.

Comment: я вообще не в теме сертификатов, но, мне кажется, если у вас несколько вопросов - то лучше из задавать отдельно, а не кучей - это и вам больше даст внимания, и отвечающие срубят больше плюсиков.

Comment: Google по запросу `powershell makecert`, вторая же ссылка: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps 
Там же рядом описание всех коммандлетов модуля PKIClient.

Comment: Я смотрел эту документацию, пробовал использовать, но выходит в конечном итоге ошибка предоставленные пакету учётные данные не были распознаны.
Создал сертификат:
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName имямашины -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
он появился в личных.
Дальше экспортировал закрытый ключ и обратно его импортировал в личные PFX файлом. Пробовал в программе в качестве параметра использовать и сам сертификат и сертификат с открытым ключом, ошибка выходит одна и та же.

Пробовал разные вариации, но видимо я плохо понимаю что я делаю и просто случайно тыкаюсь.